# Reordering Matrix blocks by date in the control panel when saving an entry

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, modules, order

I'm trying to reorder Matrix Blocks in date order when saving an entry in the control panel. I kind of have it working using the following code.

My Matrix field is 'events'. Each block contains a date field called 'startDate'.

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, function(ModelEvent $e) {
    // @var Entry $entry
    $entry = $e->sender;

    if (ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)) {
        return;
    }

    $blocks = $entry->getFieldValue('events')->orderBy('startDate ASC');
    
    $entry->setFieldValue('events', $blocks);

});
```

My problem is that I have to save the Entry TWICE for the above code to actually work. I've read that I should maybe use EVENT_AFTER_PROPAGATE instead but when I try that I can't get it to work at all.

Does anybody know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out. Here is my working solution.

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_AFTER_PROPAGATE, function(ModelEvent $e) {
    // @var Entry $entry
    $entry = $e->sender;

    if (ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)) {
        return;
    }

    if ($entry->section->handle != 'events') {
        return;
    }

    $old = $entry->getFieldValue('events');

    $new = (clone $old)->orderBy('startDate ASC');

    if ($old->ids() == $new->ids()) {
        return;
    }
    
    $entry->setFieldValue('events', $new);
    Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);

});
```

Hopefully this helps somebody :)